# How can I interpret below mentioned UTF-8 range

Tags: java, utf-8, utf

I came through below if-loop

```
 if (((current >= 0x20) && (current <= 0xD7FF))
                || ((current >= 0xE000) && (current <= 0xFFFD))
                || ((current >= 0x10000) && (current <= 0x10FFFF))) {

            out.append(current);

        }
```

I am trying to search for what does these range represent, but nowhere i am getting the answer. Can you help me interpret these ranges?

Comment: Probably UTF-8 codepoints: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) and [http://www.utf8-chartable.de/](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

Answer (score 1):

These are the valid ranges for unicode character above space. 
Below 0x20 is control characters (including new lines and tabs)
Between 0xD800 and 0xDFFF is used for encoding characters > 0xFFFF using UTF-16.

Note: if current is a `char` then `current >= 0x10000` is always false. If `current` is an `int` then `out.append(current);` will print the number not characters.